# How do you bind to a list item?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListBox` on a page that uses the following data template defined in the `Resource` section of the control.

```
<mvvm:ViewObject.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type discovery:FabricTierMetadata}">
        <fabricman:FabricManInstanceItem Metadata="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</mvvm:ViewObject.Resources>
```

What I *mean* to write is bind the current list item, but what's happening instead is the `Metadata={Binding}` is binding to the view model of the control (instead of the item in the list). How do I write it so that it associates the list item rather than the current view model?

```
<mvvm:ViewObject.Resources>
    <fabricman:MyConverter x:Key="Converter" />
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type discovery:FabricTierMetadata}">
            <fabricman:FabricManInstanceItem Metadata="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</mvvm:ViewObject.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <TabItem Header="Clouds">
            <ListBox Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableClouds}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I added a converter for debugging purposes (so I could see what was being sent through).

The background source code:

```
internal class FabricServiceManagerVM : ViewModelBase<FabricServiceManagerVM>
{
    public ViewModelCollection<FabricTierMetadata> AvailableClouds { get; private set; }

    public FabricServiceManagerVM()
    {
        this.AvailableClouds = new ViewModelCollection<FabricTierMetadata>();
        FabricServicingModel.ServiceManagerSetChanged += FabricServicingModel_ServiceManagerSetChanged;
    }

    void FabricServicingModel_ServiceManagerSetChanged(object sender, Model.Events.FabricServicingEndpointsChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ServiceDiscoveryMetadata metadata = args.Metadatas.First();
        this.AvailableClouds.Add(new FabricTierMetadata(metadata.Name, metadata.Address)); 
    }
}
```

`ViewModelCollection<T>` is essentially a beefed up `ObservableCollection`.

The `ListBox` is showing the correct number of items in my `AvailableClouds` collection, which is right.... but when it goes to apply the `DataTemplate` it's sending the wrong item though. Should be sending an instance of `FabricTierMetadata` but instead is sending through the view-model.

**Update**:

When I do this:

```
            <ListBox Background="Transparent" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableClouds}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

It shows the `Name` property just fine? Yet when I say just `{Binding}` alone, I get the VM.

Comment: Can you show ListBox XAML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Give the template a key and assign it as `StaticResource` to the `ItemsPanelTemplate` property.

```
<mvvm:ViewObject.Resources>
    <fabricman:MyConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FabricTierItem" DataType="{x:Type discovery:FabricTierMetadata}">
        <fabricman:FabricManInstanceItem Metadata="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</mvvm:ViewObject.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <TabItem Header="Clouds">
            <ListBox ItemsPanelTemplate="{StaticResource FabricTierItem}" 
                     Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableClouds}" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Actually, this still does the same thing. I thought it was working, but I still had code from the other answer in place.  It's binding to the VM still for some reason.

Comment: Ideally, I'd rather not have that.

Comment: Odd, it should work. I used that approach a thousand times. Well try the following. Updating now.

Comment: Ok, from your orginal binding (the first you posted) you wanted to have the VM. What did you expect to get?

Comment: Okay, your update gives me the `FabricTierItem` encased in a `ListBoxItem`, which is closer. Is there a way just to get the `FabricTierItem`?

Comment: So what do you expect to get? I've to admit I read your post 3 times and I still think that you want to have the item of `AvailableClouds` collection. So my current post is delivering this item to the `MetaData` property of your `FabricManInstanceItem` class. So I'm asking again. What is it what you want?

Comment: Huh, looks like someone marked down several of the answers here but gave no explanation. How nice. In any case, I built a little MVVM framework of sorts which automatically sets the view model on objects when they are created. So when the ListItem was binding with the data from the parent, it was getting automatically overwritten by another view-model because, well I kinda told it to. So this actually works, the problem was coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Hmm sounds a bit odd. ;o) But well glad I could help.

Comment: Yeah, having second thoughts now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type discovery:FabricTierMetadata}">
    <fabricman:FabricManInstanceItem Metadata="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Perfect. Weirdly roundabout, but perfect.